# Parent Container Edge Blur Transition Bug

Tags: html, css, webkit, blur

I'm trying to blur a background Div that is inside a wrapping div.

When I transition the opacity of the child div (the div that is being blurred), the blur seems to be propagating up to the parent element during the transition, causing the feathered edges, then removing itself after.

**HTML / Jade**

```
div
  div( class="bg" style="background: url('http://placekitten.com/300') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;")
```

**SCSS**

```
div  {
  cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
  .bg{
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    transition: 550ms ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px; width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
div:hover {
  .bg {
    opacity: .6;
  }
}
```

Here is a codepen showing the bug. (happening in chrome)

http://codepen.io/LAzzam2/pen/kXdwWp

Anyone know of any fix to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an SVG filter could be a good fix-

http://codepen.io/LAzzam2/pen/pbmAJB

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg">
    <svg id="svg-image">
        <image x="0" y="0" id="svg-image" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/300" />

        <filter id="blur-effect-1">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
        </filter>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#svg-image-blur { height: 220px; width: 320px; }

.bg {
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%) scale( 1.05 );
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 450px; width: 450px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}

#svg-image { 
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  filter:url(#blur-effect-1); 
}

.bg:hover {
  opacity: .6;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%) scale( 1.15 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or. Just wrap the background image and animate that element's transforms. Blur the child of that animated element.

http://codepen.io/LAzzam2/pen/kXdwWp

**HTML**
    div
      .wrap
        div( class="bg" style="background: url('http://placekitten.com/300') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;")

**CSS**

```
div  {
  cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
  .wrap {
    transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  }
  .bg{
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    transition: 550ms ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px; left: -10px;
    width: calc( 100% + 20px );
    height: calc( 100% + 20px );
    }
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px; width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
div:hover {
  .wrap {
    opacity: .6;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```